# A sealed container contains 90 % hydrogen and 10 % oxygen. There is a spark in the container. What happens?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, combustion

A sealed container contains 90 % hydrogen and 10 % oxygen. There is a spark in the container. What happens?
Assuming it is a 10-litre volume container like a fuel tank.

Comment: What do you think happens? Lets work this step by step. Would you happen to know the volume of the sealed container?

Comment: For volume, assume a 10 litre container/fuel tank.

Comment: Why Volume it is crucial here, given that you know the composition? Are you asking for absolute values like energy and damages? That would depends on the container walls and gases amount, too :)

Answer (score 3):

[Boom!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_safety#Mixtures)

> "The flammability limits based on the volume percent of hydrogen in air at 14.7 psia (1 atm, 101 kPa) are 4.0 and 75.0. The flammability limits based on the volume percent of hydrogen in oxygen at 14.7 psia (1 atm, 101 kPa) are 4.0 and 94.0."

Quoted from:

Gregory, Frederick D. (February 12, 1997). "Safety Standard for Hydrogen and Hydrogen Systems" (PDF). NASA. Retrieved 2008-05-09.